# Aggregation to bucket consecutive records that have the same values

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build a Gantt chart based on a boolean field from a time series data. My records in an ES index looks like this:

```
{date: '2022-01-01', value: true}
{date: '2022-01-02', value: true}
{date: '2022-01-03', value: true}
{date: '2022-01-04', value: false}
{date: '2022-01-05', value: true}
{date: '2022-01-06', value: false}
{date: '2022-01-07', value: true}
{date: '2022-01-08', value: true}
{date: '2022-01-09', value: false}
{date: '2022-01-10', value: false}
{date: '2022-01-11', value: false}
{date: '2022-01-12', value: true}
{date: '2022-01-13', value: false}
{date: '2022-01-14', value: true}
{date: '2022-01-15', value: true}
{date: '2022-01-16', value: false}
{date: '2022-01-17', value: false}
{date: '2022-01-18', value: false}
{date: '2022-01-19', value: true}
{date: '2022-01-20', value: true}
```

I need to retrieve the start and end dates of each date range that starts with `true` and ends with `true`. As soon as `false` is encountered, the bucket has to be stopped. A new bucket has to be created when the next `true` is encountered.

The output would be something like this:

```
{start: '2022-01-01', end: '2022-01-03'}
{start: '2022-01-05', end: '2022-01-05'}
{start: '2022-01-07', end: '2022-01-08'}
{start: '2022-01-12', end: '2022-01-12'}
{start: '2022-01-14', end: '2022-01-15'}
{start: '2022-01-19', end: '2022-01-20'}
```

I'll then use these date ranges to plot a Gantt chart like this:

[image: gantt chart]

I looked at various [bucket aggregations in ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket.html) but looks like none of them solve this type of problem. Am I overlooking? Is this possible with Elasticsearch aggregation?